# Where are IE authcookies saved?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, cookies

I am trying to pragmatically read  auth cookie related to my localhost site- an ASP.Net webforms site.

Where are auth cookies saved in IE (I am using IE 11)
When I look at the folder **C:\Users\UserOne\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCookies**, I can see a file named IIJTLKNG.

text inside it is : proxy
http://localhost:48637/proxy/0/
localhost/
0
3021396480
30421245
2419657575
30421245
*

My Web Application url in fact is http://localhost:5641/default2.aspx. I do not understand why it is shown as a proxy.This will make my task of identifying it among other cookies.

Also I had enabled forms authentication with

```
 <forms name=".MYAUTHCOOKIE"  ....... />
```

But I don't see MYAUTHCOOKIE at all inside the file I mentioned above! Why?

Is the actual MYAUTHCOOKIE cookie saved somewhere else?

Comment: likely it is encrypted.

Comment: @DanielA.White, I guess so.just looking for a means to retrieve it though.

Comment: You can check to see if a variable holds a value, but I'm not sure if you can actually read the value.  I use this line in some of my code If HttpContext.Current.Session("username") Is Nothing Then

Comment: why do you need to know where the physical file of the cookie is? You can simply just read the cookies thru the HttpResponse object

Comment: @RomanCanlas. I am trying to read it from another application (a wpf desktop app). as in this one..  http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iecookies.html. But you have a point I see. Thnx